# C#: Combining AddRange() and Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, html-agility-pack

I have a `Collection` of nodes, specifically a collection of `HTMLAgilityPack.HTMLNodeCollection` nodes. I know I can extract and store information from the nodes by doing:

```
List<string> nodesList = new List<string>();

var nodes = myFile.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(file_path);
foreach (var node in nodes)
    nodesList.Add(node.InnerText);
```

However, what I would like to do is apply `AddRange()`, rather than add the items in a `foreach` loop. I'm trying to use a lambda expression to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with lambda expressions to do it properly. I'm trying to combine something like

```
nodesList.AddRange( string[] arr = x => nodes.ToArray()[x].InnerText );
```

I know that makes no syntactical sense, but I'm not sure if can even do this. I would like to just `Cast<string>()` the collection, but I need to extract the text from each node.

Any ideas on how to put this into an `AddRange()` expression?

Comment: @GrantWinney Yep. Should it not?

Comment: @GrantWinney Haha, you're right. I mistyped into SO. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `IEnumerable.Select()`:

```
nodesList.AddRange(nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText))
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Right you are. I did a lazy search for HTMLAgilityPack documentation and didn't find anything about how its `HTMLNodeCollection` was implemented... so, I just installed it to confirm.